# Shorthand functions for multiple geoms in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create shorthand notations or functions that combines multiple geoms for ggplot.
For example, instead of

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  ggpubr::stat_cor()
```

I would like to be able to create a function to combine the geoms like so

```
lm_and_cor <- function() {
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
    stat_cor()
}

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  lm_and_cor()
```

I am aware that I can create functions that does all of the plotting, basically

```
plot_data <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    ggpubr::stat_cor()
}
```

which to be fair *does* what I want, to some degree. However, I would instead like to combine multiple geoms in a single function, as the underlying geom (e.g. point, lines, etc.) will not always be the same. Is this doable, and is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ggplot2 you can use `list` of elements:

```
lm_and_cor <- function()
  list(geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE),
       ggpubr::stat_cor()
  )

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  lm_and_cor()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?
You can store multiple geom in a list object.

Edit: I misunderstand the question. This should meet the expectation.

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)

x <- list(geom_point(), geom_line())
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + x
```

[image]

Or if you want to make a function to plot by column use this {{variable}}.

```
library(dplyr)

plotting <- function(data, x, y){
  data %>% 
  ggplot(aes({{x}}, {{y}})) +
           geom_point() +
           geom_smooth(method = "lm")}

plotting(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
```

[image]